# error: filename expected press any key to continue

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and before installing, it asked if I wanted to wipe the hard drive or install alongside my Linux Lite 2.6. I chose to install alongside. So it installed Ubuntu, but now Linux Lite won't boot. I get: 
    error: filelename expected press any key to continue.

What can I do be able to boot both my Linux Lite 2.6 and my Ubuntu 14.04? I havent  tried anything; I barely figured out how to access grub2 command prompt but I have no idea what to do there.

Answer (score 1):

The Linux Lite team made a modification to GRUB2 that causes this problem on  multi-boot machines when another distro is installed after Linux Lite. The solution is to use the Linux Lite GRUB2 boot loader instead of the Ubuntu (or other distro) boot loader.
The steps for doing this are described by gold-finger in his response to this post: https://www.linuxliteos.com/forums/suggestions-and-feedback/grub-quirk/msg2431.
Cheers!